# How can I sort these?

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I've been trying for a couple of hours now but I can't get it fixed (I'm new to coding/python).

```
with open('spelers.csv', 'r') as speler_lijst:
                spelers_lijst_lezen = csv.reader(speler_lijst, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                for line in spelers_lijst_lezen:
                    print(line[0],"\t", line[1])
```

So I have it that it prints all my inputs from the csv file like:

```
1    Name 1
5    Name 5
10   Name 10
2    Name 2
```

Now I'd like to sort them. But all the things I have tried give me errors or not the effect wished for.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried and the errors you get.

Comment: Could you add the CSV file so we can run a working example? You might want to look at numpys argsort-function.

Comment: How do I add the csv? (Sorry new to coding and this website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
with open('spelers.csv', 'r') as speler_lijst:
    spelers_lijst_lezen = csv.reader(speler_lijst, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in sorted(spelers_lijst_lezen, key=lambda i: i[0]):
        print(line[0],"\t", line[1])
```

In `lambda` function use index you want to sort

EDIT: if your sort key is not string use int cast:

```
sorted(spelers_lijst_lezen, key=lambda i: int(i[0]))
```

Comment: This works for sorting indeed, making it one step closer. But it sorts on first digit, then second etc. So 1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21, etc
I think it's because I made those out of inputs earlier. So I'd need to make the first part into an int I guess

Comment: You may want `int(i[0])` in the key function, since the sorting should probably be done numerically (`10` goes after `2` in a numeric sort, while `"10"` is ahead of `"2"` in a lexicographical string sort).

Comment: Yes fixed the issue. Thanks all